# How do I stop tikz from using scientific notation in the y axis?

Tags: pgfplots, axis, scientific-notation

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=plot,
width=0.75\textwidth,
height=\axisdefaultheight,
xmin=0, xmax=18,
ymin=0, ymax=0.2,
minor tick num=1,
scaled ticks = false,
ytick distance=0.05,
xlabel={$V \, (\mathrm{mL})$},
ylabel={$\mathrm{Abs}$},
every axis plot/.append style={thick},
legend pos={north east}]
\addplot[RoyalBlue, mark=*] table[x index=0,y index=1]{dextrano.txt};
\addlegendentry{$\mathrm{Abs_{620\, nm}}$ Dext.};

\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Cromatografia do Azul de dextrano]{Cromatografia do Azul de dextrano: Abs$_{620}$ em função do volume de eluição}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=18,
ymin=0, ymax=0.2,
minor tick num=1,
ytick distance=0.05,
xlabel={$V \, (\mathrm{mL})$},
ylabel={$\mathrm{Abs}$},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Empty graph]